# Direct proof that a short exact sequence induces a quasi-isomorphism from the mapping cone

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Consider the following exact sequence of complexes in an abelian category:

[image]

I want to prove that there exists a quasi-isomorphism $\rho^\bullet:\operatorname{MC}(\varphi^\bullet)^\bullet\to N^\bullet$, where $\operatorname{MC}(\varphi^\bullet)^\bullet$ is the mapping cone of $\varphi^\bullet$.

It is clear that $\rho^\bullet$ should be the composition of the projection $\operatorname{MC}(\varphi^\bullet)^\bullet \to M^\bullet$ with the given morphism $\psi^\bullet:M^\bullet\to N^\bullet$. The usual way to continue seems to be noticing that

[image]

is an exact sequence, that $H^\bullet(K^\bullet)=0$ and using the long exact sequence in cohomology to conclude.

However, I'm trying to use this statement to prove the existence of the long exact sequence in cohomology, so I'm trying to prove that $\rho^\bullet$ is a quasi-isomorphism directly. It seems that it shouldn't be really difficult, since everything is somewhat explicit here, but I can't seem to do it. (I know how to do it using Freyd-Mitchel but I really would prefer an arrow-theoretic argument.)

Comment: If you’re only verifying exactness properties of morphisms you have explicitly constructed, it is straightforward to translate arguments using elements into arguments using subobjects. This is done by way of example in _Categories for the working mathematician_. However, if you are constructing morphisms by using elements then there is no shortcut so you either use the full strength of the embedding theorem or find a different construction.

Comment: @ZhenLin, normally I am able to do these translations but in this case I am having trouble (perhaps because of the differential, which doesn't satisfies a universal property). If you want, I can write a proof using elements here.

Comment: The differential is defined by a matrix of morphisms, surely? That’s as explicit as you could hope for!

Comment: @ZhenLin Indeed! But, for some reason, I can't seem to do it. I tried more today but without any progress.